# Keeping repository synced with multiple clients

Tags: wpf, entity-framework

I have a WPF application that uses entity framework. I am going to be implementing a repository pattern to make interactions with EF simple and more testable. Multiple clients can use this application and connect to the same database and do CRUD operations. I am trying to think of a way to synchronize clients repositories when one makes a change to the database. Could anyone give me some direction on how one would solve this type of issue, and some possible patterns that would be beneficial for this type of problem?

I would be very open to any information/books on how to keep clients synchronized, and even be alerted of things other clients are doing(The only thing I could think of was having a server process running that passes messages around). Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way by far to keep every client UI up to date is just to simply refresh the data every so often. If it's really that important, you can set a `DispatcherTimer` to tick every minute when you can get the latest data that is being displayed.

Clearly, I'm not suggesting that you refresh an item that is being edited, but if you get the fresh data, you can certainly compare collections with what's being displayed currently. Rather than just replacing the old collection items with the new, you can be more user friendly and just add the new ones, remove the deleted ones and update the newer ones.

You could even detect whether an item being currently edited has been saved by another user since the current user opened it and alert them to the fact. So rather than concentrating on some system to track all data changes, you should put your effort into being able to detect changes between two sets of data and then seamlessly integrating it into the current UI state.

---

UPDATE >>>

There is absolutely no benefit from holding a complete set of data in your application (or repository). In fact, you may well find that it adds detrimental effects, due to the extra RAM requirements. If you are polling data every few minutes, then it will always be up to date anyway.

So rather than asking for all of the data all of the time, just ask for what the user wants to see (dependant on which view they are currently in) and update it every now and then. I do this by simply fetching the same data that the view requires when it is first opened. I wrote some methods that compare every property of every item with their older counterparts in the UI and switch old for new.

Think of the `Equals` method... You could do something like this:

```
public override bool Equals(Release otherRelease)
{
    return base.Equals(otherRelease) && Title == otherRelease.Title && 
        Artist.Equals(otherRelease.Artist) && Artists.Equals(otherRelease.Artists);
}
```

(Don't actually use the `Equals` method though, or you'll run into problems later). And then something like this:

```
if (!oldRelease.Equals(newRelease)) oldRelease.UpdatePropertyValues(newRelease);
```

And/Or this:

```
if (!oldReleases.Contains(newRelease) oldReleases.Add(newRelease);
```

I'm guessing that you get the picture now.

Comment: Thanks. That makes a lot of sense. I am curious as to what would be a fast way to see what new entities have been added to the DB in EF. If I am to understand the repository pattern correctly, my "Customer" repo. would have all of the EF customer entities, and the repo would poll the DB every so often and find new customers. How would I detect what new entities are in the DB vs. what my repo list currently has without brute forcing it? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the update. It all makes perfect sense. I guess I was having issues with what the repository actually stores, and why it is beneficial to keep things the user accessed in memory if they aren't likely to need it again.